# Output Result of Formula In Cell Different From Formula Location

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm needing to output the results from a formula in a cell different from where the formula is. The reason is that the data above the cell in which the formula has been placed is dynamic, and might spill down into the cell where the formula is.

**Is there a way to do this in Excel?**

Looking at the picture below, the data in the **Projects Won - Monthly** section is dynamic, and is being filtered to this sheet from a separate worksheet in the same workbook. The length of this data can change, and often will run into the data set beneath it, in the **Project Won - YTD** section.

So, I'm often tasked with manually inserting rows to adjust for the length of the first set of data in Projects Won - Monthly.

I'm envisioning something where I could insert another column and have it be column A. In that column, I would have a formula that would detect the last non-blank cell address from the first data set (which would now be in column B), and then output the second filtered data set 2 rows beneath the first data set, depending upon which row that first data set ends.

So, let's say I put this formula in cell A7. This formula would detect the last non-empty cell from the first data set in column B, which is currently in B7, and then output the second data set 2 rows down starting in B9, since the first data set happens to end in B7, always leaving a blank row between the data sets.

Any ideas on how I could accomplish this?

Here's my current formula for the second data set on the left, which is pulling in data from another tab. According to the image below, this formula is in cell A10.

```
=IFERROR(VSTACK({"Date","Pursuit Lead","Project Name","Est. Amount"},CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Success_Rate___Monthly___2024,(Success_Rate___Monthly___2024[Stage]="Closed Won")*(Success_Rate___Monthly___2024[Last Name]=I1)),{7,8,6,5})),"No projects won yet this fiscal year")
```

***Goal: To sum up, the goal is to always have a blank row between the first and second data sets.***

I'm thinking that having the output of the formula in a different cell location than the formula itself might help to accomplish this, without the use of VBA.

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `=VSTACK(Formula_in_A3,INDEX(CHAR(160),,SEQUENCE(1,4,1,0)),Formula_in_A10)` - the labels in rows 2 & 9 could also be included (with an appropriate LET() function) and, if you need the highlighting then you could implement conditional formatting.

Comment: @SpectralInstance by golly you've done it. It's a long formula, but it works. If you have some time, would love to hear your thoughts on using LET to bring in rows 2 and 9. The titles for each data set in A2 and A9 are static. But, there are formulas in C2, D2, C9 and D9 to automatically calculate total amounts and numbers for each.

Answer (score 0):

So, SpectralInstance commented, providing a great solution, and so I thought I'd post it here, and break down what I did to make his suggestion work. I had posted the following formula above, as a formula used to create the first data set I screenshot in the image above, with the formula in A3, which output the data down and to the right until D7.

```
=IFERROR(VSTACK({"Date","Pursuit Lead","Project Name","Est. Amount"},CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Success_Rate___Monthly___2024,(Success_Rate___Monthly___2024[Stage]="Closed Won")*(Success_Rate___Monthly___2024[Last Name]=I1)),{7,8,6,5})),"No projects won yet this fiscal year")
```

Here's the breakdown of what I did to infuse his solution into what I currently had to make it work. Hope this helps anyone that might come across this in the future apply this for their situation. For reference, here's the code that SpectralInstance posted as a comment...

```
=VSTACK(Formula_in_A3,INDEX(CHAR(160),,SEQUENCE(1,4,1,0)),Formula_in_A10)
```

***SOLUTION BREAKDOWN***

**1️⃣** To start off, I took the very first part of his code, and placed it at the front of my formula...

```
=VSTACK(
```

**2️⃣** I then added my formula for the first data set, in A3...

```
IFERROR(VSTACK({"Date","Pursuit Lead","Project Name","Est. Amount"},CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Success_Rate___Monthly___2024,(Success_Rate___Monthly___2024[Stage]="Closed Won")*(Success_Rate___Monthly___2024[Last Name]=I1)),{7,8,6,5})),"No projects won yet this fiscal year")
```

**3️⃣** Next, I added the middle portion of the code he provided...

```
,INDEX(CHAR(160),,SEQUENCE(1,4,1,0)),
```

**4️⃣** Finally, I added the formula for the second data set, which is located in A10, followed by one final closing parenthesis, to close out the initial VSTACK placed at the front.

```
IFERROR(VSTACK({"Date","Pursuit Lead","Project Name","Est. Amount"},CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Success_Rate___Monthly___2024,(Success_Rate___Monthly___2024[Stage]="Closed Won")*(Success_Rate___Monthly___2024[Last Name]=I2)),{7,8,6,5})),"No projects won yet this fiscal year"))
```

Putting it all together, it looks like this, and works!

```
=VSTACK(IFERROR(VSTACK({"Date","Pursuit Lead","Project Name","Est. Amount"},CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Success_Rate___Monthly___2024,(Success_Rate___Monthly___2024[Stage]="Closed Won")*(MONTH(Success_Rate___Monthly___2024[Last Stage Change Date]) = MONTH(TODAY()))*(Success_Rate___Monthly___2024[Last Name]=I2)),{7,8,6,5})),"No projects won yet for this fiscal month"),INDEX(CHAR(160),,SEQUENCE(1,4,1,0)),IFERROR(VSTACK({"Date","Pursuit Lead","Project Name","Est. Amount"},CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Success_Rate___Monthly___2024,(Success_Rate___Monthly___2024[Stage]="Closed Won")*(Success_Rate___Monthly___2024[Last Name]=I2)),{7,8,6,5})),"No projects won yet this fiscal year"))
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: GIF illustrating operation of suggested formula]

The formula in `A1` is

```
=LET(hdrs,{"Date","Pursuit Lead","Project Name","Est. Amount"},mtd,FILTER(F2:I6,J2:J6),ytd,FILTER(L2:O8,P2:P8),VSTACK(IFERROR(VSTACK(HSTACK("Projects Won ","- Monthly",TEXT(SUM(INDEX(mtd,,4))/1000000,"_________________________ $ 0")&"M",COUNT(INDEX(mtd,,4))),hdrs,mtd),{"No MTD Projects","","",""}),CHOOSE({1,1,1,1},CHAR(160)),IFERROR(VSTACK(HSTACK("Projects Won ","- YTD",TEXT(SUM(INDEX(ytd,,4))/1000000,"_________________________ $ 0")&"M",COUNT(INDEX(ytd,,4))),hdrs,ytd),{"No YTD Projects","","",""})))
```

and conditional formatting rules have been defined as follows

[image: Screenshot illustrating conditional-formatting rules applied]

You will have to play around with how 'words' are distributed among cells since there can be no truly blank cells in a formula, so text cannot 'overlap' blank cells as it normally would in the case of manually populated cells.

Comment: This looks really cool, but I can't really have the checkboxes on the side to optionally display. It just needs to show up. But thanks so much for the suggestion.

Comment: @user14915635 the checkboxes are purely for demo purposes (as you didn't post any sample data); if you substitute the 2 `FILTER()` functions 'reading' the checkboxes with your actual `FILTER()` functions then you should be good to go.